flutter Android read NFC chip
I am trying to read an NFC chip with my Android device using Flutter. I am using flutter_nfc_kit.
My Android device seems to have NFC capabilities. I could enable "NFC and contactless payments" in the settings.
final availability = await FlutterNfcKit.nfcAvailability;
print(availability.name);

This code snippet prints available, so I guess my device is definitely NFC capable.
So, I've tried to read my NFC chip like this, but everytime it just times out:
ElevatedButton(
                child: const Text("Poll NFC"),
                onPressed: () async {
                  try {
                    final availability = await FlutterNfcKit.nfcAvailability;
                    print(availability.name);
                    final tag = await FlutterNfcKit.poll(
                      timeout: const Duration(milliseconds: 5000),
                    );
                    print(tag);
                  } catch (e) {
                    print(e.toString());
                  }
                },
              )

I take my phone, press the button, and hold the nfc chip to the back of the phone. I tried different spots on the phone in case I might have missed the nfc reader. I have these NFC chips: Amazon
I also tried the nfc_manager package, same outcome.

I recommend to install the TagInfo app by NXP on your Android device (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nxp.taginfolite). This app is developed by the company that invented the NTAG21x NFC tags and should be able to read the data on the chip - to be sure that your phone is been capable to work with NFC.

A dozen or so small loops of a wire with each end connected to legs of a LED can make a rough NFC field detector which should pulse the LED to show the location of the NFC field and aerial on the device.

With the Tag Info App I can scan the tags, so my phone is definitely capable
